# With ARC turned on, is there a different between alloc/init and normal autorelease methods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, autorelease

What is the different between these two when using ARC in Objective-C for iOS?

```
NSMutableArray *anArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:itemsArray];
appDelegate.wishlistItemsArray = anArray;
```

vs

```
appDelegate.wishlistItemsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:itemsArray];
```

The property in appDelegate is:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *wishlistItemsArray;
```

Comment: FYI - another option is: `appDelegate.wishlistItemsArray = [itemsArray mutableCopy];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. Those methods differ only in the memory management semantics of their return value, and ARC handles memory management for you, they can be used interchangeably in an ARC program.